# How do I make this web service call fault tolerant?

Tags: database, web-services, wcf, iis, asp.net-web-api

We have a WinForms desktop app that connects to a remote server to pull some data. The remote server hosts a web service on a standard IIS website that queries a SQL Server database installed on the same machine. Today, if the remote server is under maintenance or not available our end-user cannot retrieve the necessary data.

Now I am requested to make this feature fault-tolerant. Here are my questions:

1. Should I ask for another remote server that runs the same web service and move the DB to a third remote server? So the two web services can connect to the same DB?
2. Should I consider moving the web service logic to the WinForms desktop app and connect directly to a remote DB paying a first-class 99.99% availability service?
3. Do AWS or Azure provide a ready-to-use solution that fulfills my requirements?
4. Is there any other option I didn't consider?

Comment: If you are willing to pay AWS or Azure, then why not contact their presales team to help determine how you will use the services? They already support tons of high available sites all around the world, so yours isn't more complicated.

Comment: They have tons of services, I don't know even how to name this one.

Comment: You don't need to name any service yourself. Give them a call and they will be happy to guide you, as you are going to be a paid customer.